# I did not understand the notepad sample in samples

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi i did not understand the notepad sample in android.when i import this to my workspace it shows there are no projects.Its having sqlite code i want to see how this application running,Please explain it once

Answer (score 1):

First of all your question is not clear...

Do you mean that after importing this project into eclipse you are unable to see it on your workspace located in ur PC ? If yes then you need to import them on your workspace.

By default while opening a project it remains in the respective physical location on the disk unless we explicitly mention that it needs to copy the project on to the workspace.  On eclipse right click select Import-->General -->Existing projects on workspace-->select your project location and check copy projects into workspace. This would copy your project to the workspace.

Comment: My question is in that notepad tutorial contains two Android manifest files ,When i copy that notapad  app  into workspace and   right click select Import-->General -->Existing projects on workspace-->browse that notepad app at that time it show there are no applications

Comment: hmmm... An application cannot have 2 Manifest files..something is wrong...Take this approach.. Right click on Eclipse... Select New-->Android Project-->select your project path there and check if it works.. Notepad app comes as an inbuilt application in SDK samples... It would be in the following location android-sdk-windows\samples\android-8\NotePad and it works for me